# UINavigationController jarring push transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm using the latest iOS 7 animation transitions protocols in order to create a fade transition one a push a view controller; a member of the class `PSSpaceDetailViewController`. However, for all other push transitions, I'd like to use the default push animation that `UINavigationController` normally provides.

However, having implemented the following code to do exactly that, I'm receiving a strange delayed jarring animation when I push a separate view controller from the aforementioned class. Any ideas why this is happening? I've uploaded a short video showing the animation that I'm trying to describe which will hopefully make it easier to understand the bug: http://d.pr/v/Q754

```
//PSAnimatngNavigationControllerDelegate.m

+ (instancetype) sharedInstance {
    static PSAnimatingNavigationControllerDelegate *shared;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        shared = [[PSAnimatingNavigationControllerDelegate alloc] init];
    });
    return shared;
}

- (PSFadeAnimator *) animator {
    if (!_animator) {
        _animator = [[PSFadeAnimator alloc] init];
    }
    return _animator;
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
{
    if (operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPush && [toVC isKindOfClass:[PSSpaceDetailViewController class]]) {
        return self.animator;
    }
    return nil;
}

// App Delegate.m

UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:notesViewController];
[navigationController setDelegate:[PSAnimatingNavigationControllerDelegate sharedInstance]];

PSSpaceDetailViewController.m

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PSMatchDetailViewController *matchDetail = [[PSMatchDetailViewController alloc] initWithOriginalSpace:self.space andPotentialLead:self.datasource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:matchDetail animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view controller you're pushing has an `nil` background colour, which defaults to clear on iOS 7. Just set it to white or whatever and it'll work.